# No Layout Editor in the latest Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-studio-arctic-fox, android-layout-editor

I have got this weird problem while upgraded to the latest Android Studio. It has no Layout Editor, no Design Tab or Preview Tab. Has anyone faced similar problem? Please help me out.

Image 1[image: 1]

Image 2[image: 2]

Image 3[image: 3]

Comment: try installing it fresh you will get that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved it by reinstalling and restoring to default settings, would be a help to anyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Bumblebee version.

I could get it back by going to : File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore default settings